# How do you use the accessibility ID in a Cypress Selector?

Tags: cypress, accessibility, webautomation

In the Chrome Dev Tools display, there is an accessibility tree that lists accessibility IDs for all of the elements on the page. I want to use these IDs as my selectors when I am writing cypress tests using cy.get(selector).

We can select by accessibility ID in Webdriver IO using:

```
const elem = $('~my_accessibility_identifier')
elem.click()
```

What is the correct selector format to use for cypress?

Comment: Looking at https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors.html#accessibility-id that seems to only be for iOS and Android. For accessibility-based selections in Cypress you could use https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro/, using the ByRole selectors per https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority

Comment: You can have a look at this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-axe. I believe `cy.checkA11y()` is what you're looking for.